# require an ordered vector for struct initialization

Tags: rust

I have a struct:

```
pub struct OneDLookup <T: PartialOrd + Sub + Add + Copy + Clone, U: Add + Sub + Copy + Clone>{
    breakpoints: Vec<T>,
    values: Vec<U>,
    last_diff_bp: f64,      //ignore these, they are not important to this question
    last_diff_values: f64,
    first_diff_bp: f64,
    first_diff_values: f64,
}
```

This will function as a lookup table, however there are 2 important things that have to be true about this struct:

breakpoints must be in ascending order 1,5,7,9 for example, and not any other order.
breakpoints and values must have the same length.

Is it possible to check these at compile time (or even better with the rust-analyzer during writing) in a macro? I fear it might not be.

I'm quite new to rust so I'm still learning the ins and outs.

I tried to make a tiny macro that doesn't work based on the `vec!()` macro to see if I could understand what was done there but unfortunately I have no idea:

```
macro_rules! create_1d_lookup {
    (($($bps:expr,)*); ($($vals:expr,)*)) => (
        $crate::my_crate::OneDLookup::new(vec![$($bps),+], vec![$($vals),+])
    );
}
```

OneDLookup::new() takes the breakpoints and values vectors as arguments.

This struct is constant and will not change after initialization.

Comment: Are the values always known at compile time?

Comment: yes these values will be manually filled in at the start

Comment: In the start of what?

Comment: yes i guess, just yes, these values are known at compile time. The purpose of this struct is to be global, and then used throughout a program. ( it represents a sensor for example to convert values from measurement to physical value )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by creating a `const` that runs some logic to verify the invariants are upheld and panics if they're broken. The panic will be translated into a compilation failure:

```rust
macro_rules! create_1d_lookup {
    (($($bps:expr,)*); ($($vals:expr,)*)) => {{
        const _: () = {
            let breakpoints = [ $($bps,)* ];
            if breakpoints.len() != [ $($vals,)* ].len() {
                // There are multiple ways to count in macros,
                // this is the simplest assuming the expressions are side-effect-free.
                panic!("sizes of vectors don't match");
            }

            let mut i = 1;
            // Can't use a `for` loop in consts currently.
            while i < breakpoints.len() {
                if breakpoints[i - 1] > breakpoints[i] {
                    panic!("breakpoints aren't sorted");
                }
                i += 1;
            }
        };
        $crate::my_crate::OneDLookup::new(vec![$($bps),+], vec![$($vals),+])
    }};
}
```

Unfortunately, this is a post-monomorphization error, meaning it won't show up in `cargo check`, only in `cargo build`.